# How to use && in EL boolean expressions in Facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets, el

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to do and's on EL expressions in Facelets.
So basically I have:

```
<h:outputText id="Prompt"
    value="Fobar" 
    rendered="#{beanA.prompt == true && beanB.currentBase !=null}" />
```

But I keep getting:

> Error Traced[line: 69] The entity name must immediately follow the '&'
>   in the entity reference.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. The `&` is a [special character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) in XML representing the start of an entity like `&amp;` which ends with the `;` character. You'd need to either escape it, which is ugly:

```
rendered="#{beanA.prompt == true &amp;&amp; beanB.currentBase != null}"
```

or to use the `and` keyword instead, which is preferred as to readability and maintainability:

```
rendered="#{beanA.prompt == true and beanB.currentBase != null}"
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Operators in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, comparing booleans with booleans makes little sense when the expression expects a boolean outcome already. I'd get rid of `== true`:

```
rendered="#{beanA.prompt and beanB.currentBase != null}"
```

Comment: The JSF imlementation should really recognize this case and give a better diagnostic. It's a simple problem, but very confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer of BalusC, use the following Java RegExp to replace `&&` with `and`:

```
Search:  (#\{[^\}]*)(&&)([^\}]*\})
Replace: $1and$3
```

You have run this regular expression replacement multiple times to find all occurences in case you are using >2 literals in your EL expressions. Mind to replace the leading # by $ if your EL expression syntax differs.