# Reusable actionListener attribute - avoid null value - Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, facelets, taglib

I am watching this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420567/6312069) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552922/6312069) which describes how to make `actionListener` for example being reusable in case of facelets as :

```
<my:tag ... bean="#{myBean}" actionMethod="preFillData" />

...

<h:commandButton ... action="#{bean[actionMethod]}" />
```

It is good. The thing is I am confused about what if the values are **null** for example? *Something like this but I am not sure is it workable in case jsf syntax (see next snippet)* :

**not tested**

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{(bean==null||actionMethod==null?myBeanB[myMethodB]:bean[actionMethod])}" />
```

*The alike expression is causes `Illegal Syntax for Set Operation` exception being thrown... so I am not sure about the syntax :*(*

So my question is... how to analyze the attribute(s) have values on client side?

Comment: I am really confused about el expression in case of complicated boolean expression so any tip would be very helpful :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use `if...else` as :

```
<c:if test="#{bean!=null and actionMethod!=null}">
    <c:set var="variableAction" value="#{bean[actionMethod]}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{bean==null or actionMethod==null}">
    <c:set var="variableAction" value="#{somedefaultbean.method}"/>
    </c:if>

...

<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{variableAction}" />
```

p.s.The solution is working fine but I am still looking for a shorter one so please feel free to add comments and helpful tips :)

Cheers